# another way then the function stacking in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, reference

I am looking for a better method of doing something that is common in JavaScript. How do I do this:

```
// global namespace
var PlexLib = PlexLib || {};
PlexLib = {
    FileName : "",
    ShowName : "",
    AddFileSelector_result : function (data,status,xhr) {
        console.log ("Callback here." + data);
        console.log ("Callback here." + status);
        console.log ("Callback here." + xhr);
    },
    AddFileSelector : function () {
        var afs = this.AddFileSelector_result();
        $.get(script_name ,"AddFileSelector=AddFileSelector",afs,"html");
    },
    RemoveFileSelector : function () {
        console.log ("Do Remove.");
    },
}
```

Ok, at `$.get(script_name ,"AddFileSelector=AddFileSelector",afs,"html")`
the problem is with `afs`.

The specification of .get request is:

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

What I am getting up above is when the callback occurs, I am either getting 'undefined' in the data, (`data,status,xhr`) or, the entire script passed in. I have no idea how that's happening either.

So, what I am asking is, when I see a definition like:

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

How do I do the `function(data,status,xhr)` part, I want it to be a reference to a normal:

```
function () {
}
```

defined someplace else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the function here:

```
var afs = this.AddFileSelector_result();
```

Pass it as a pointer:

```
var afs = this.AddFileSelector_result;
```

so that when the AJAX request completes it will be invoked with the proper arguments.

Comment: Well, that stopped the 'undefined'.  I am now getting the contents of the script in `data`.  the server process is supposed to respond with `<p>Script Here</p>`  I have tried the request manually, `?AddFileSelector=AddFileSelector' and it does respond correctly.  Is there something else I am mssing?

Comment: Aren't you getting the expected result in the `data` variable? Have you looked at the Network tab to analyze the exact data being sent back? Also is the request pointing to the correct url?

Comment: Well, yes and no.  The script is served from the php script because it edits some fields before it puts it in to the page.  After looking at the network pane, I saw that `JS` is still being sent back.  I don't know why `.get` is including it.  I reversed the order in my CASE select statement to look for AddFileSelector first, and am getting correct result now, but why is `.get` producing `?JS&AddFileSelector=AddFileSelector`  `JS` was the query from the script header to only get the javascript, but not included in the above .get query.???

Comment: Try passing the parameter like this: `$.get(script_name, { AddFileSelector: 'AddFileSelector' }, afs, 'html');` Also check the `script_name` variable contents. I suspect that it already contains the `?JS` part which is why it gets sent. So make sure that this `script_name` variable points to the actual script without any other query string parameters.

Comment: nope, it's still adding it.  I know that script_name does not include it.  I checked for that.   Could it be something jQuery on how it determines the name of the script?  The HTML that requested the page was `echo '<script src="'. $script_name .'?JS" type="text/javascript"></script>';` could jQuery be confused on how this was done?  (I move and rename my scripts alot, so....) btw, your answer its self, does it work anytime I see `function()` as a parameter?

Comment: I would be surprised if the `.get` method would include the `JS` parameter to the AJAX request just because it was present when the script was included. You can always test if this is the case by removing it from the server when rendering this `script` tag. So you have checked that `alert(script_name);` produces the expected value? By the way from your code it isn't quite clear where and how is this `script_name` javascript variable defined. Could you clarify that?

Comment: Found it.  It was in the PHP, I strip the uri and path from the url of the script, but not the parameters, and it was branding the javascript with the name + parameters, and at the time, JS was in there.  Doh!  Thanks!!!